# Highlight target container in Dragula

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ng2-dragula

I am using Dragula package to implement drag-and-drop in my Angular 2 project. It works fine. Very easy to use bundling of functionality.

https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula

But I would like to highlight target container to emphasize the location of the coming drop. Is there an easy way to do that? I know JavaScript has support for that so I just assumed it would be exposed in Dragula as well, but I just haven't found it so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was so easy that I am almost embarrassed :)

It is just a matter of using the provided over and out events.
The desired design is in this case defined in my custom CSS class "possibleTargetContainer".

```
dragulaService.over.subscribe((value) => { this.onOver(value.slice(1)); });
dragulaService.out.subscribe((value) => { this.onOut(value.slice(1)); });

private onOver(args) {
    let [el, target, source] = args;
    target.classList.add("possibleTargetContainer");
}

private onOut(args) {
    let [el, target, source] = args;
    target.classList.remove("possibleTargetContainer");
}
```

Kudos again to Dragula being a very nice and straightforward lib!